# Ansible - Looping on a list of lists one after another

Tags: list, loops, ansible, yaml

Even if this question looks rather simple (and I've been searching and testing a lot), I cannot figure out how to loop on two ore more lists in ansible in a single task.

For instance, a very simple example :

My vars.yml :

```yaml
list1:
  - /tmp/dir1
  - /tmp/dir2
  - /tmp/dir3

list2:
  - /tmp/dir4
  - /tmp/dir5
  - /tmp/dir6
```

My task:

```yaml
task:
 - name: Create basic directories if they do not exist
   file:
     path: "{{ DIRECTORY }}"
     state: directory
   loop: 
     - "{{ list1 }}"
     - "{{ list2 }}"
   loop_control:
     loop_var: DIRECTORY
```

Obviously I could create all of them in a single task in a single list, but I have ALOT to create, hence my question.

Thanks in advance,

Comment: i dont understant what you want to do.. you just declare all lists in your playbook...could you precise?    `loop on two ore more lists in ansible in a single task`  ????

Comment: Hello, I want the task to create all the dir from the list1 and then all the dir from the list2. And why not add a list3 with more directories to create.

Comment: Are you asking how to use [`| union`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/2.10/user_guide/playbooks_filters.html#selecting-from-sets-or-lists-set-theory)?

Comment: I've tried list, dict2items, or even loop: {{ [ list1, list2 ] }} with some filters in so many different ways and orders that I lost myself, but I had no clue about union. Thanks for pointed it out, I'll try it!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For example, given the lists below

```yaml
    list1:
      - /tmp/dir1
      - /tmp/dir2
      - /tmp/dir3
    list2:
      - /tmp/dir4
      - /tmp/dir5
      - /tmp/dir6
    list3:
      - /tmp/dir1
      - /tmp/dir4
      - /tmp/dir9
```

Create a list of these lists, then [*flatten*](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/devel/user_guide/playbooks_filters.html#managing-list-variables) them and select [*unique*](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/devel/user_guide/playbooks_filters.html#selecting-from-sets-or-lists-set-theory) items only, e.g.

```yaml
    list3: "{{ [list1, list2, list3]|flatten|unique }}"
```

gives probably what you are looking for

```yaml
  list3:
  - /tmp/dir1
  - /tmp/dir2
  - /tmp/dir3
  - /tmp/dir4
  - /tmp/dir5
  - /tmp/dir6
  - /tmp/dir9
```

---

You can use it in the loop, of course

```yaml
task:
 - name: Create basic directories if they do not exist
   file:
     path: "{{ DIRECTORY }}"
     state: directory
   loop: "{{ [list1, list2, list3]|flatten|unique }}"
   loop_control:
     loop_var: DIRECTORY
```

---

The situation is even simpler if the lists are stored in a file, e.g.

```yaml
shell> cat vars.yml
list1:
  - /tmp/dir1
  - /tmp/dir2
  - /tmp/dir3
list2:
  - /tmp/dir4
  - /tmp/dir5
  - /tmp/dir6
list3:
  - /tmp/dir1
  - /tmp/dir4
  - /tmp/dir9
```

Include the variables(lists) from the file into a dictionary

```yaml
    - include_vars:
        file: vars.yml
        name: lists
```

This will create the dictionary *lists*

```yaml
  lists:
    list1:
    - /tmp/dir1
    - /tmp/dir2
    - /tmp/dir3
    list2:
    - /tmp/dir4
    - /tmp/dir5
    - /tmp/dir6
    list3:
    - /tmp/dir1
    - /tmp/dir4
    - /tmp/dir9
```

Then, flatten the values and select unique items. The expression below creates the same list as before without explicitly knowing the lists, i.e. you can keep the code untouched and change the data in the file *vars.yml* only

```yaml
    list3: "{{ lists.values()|flatten|unique }}"
```

Comment: Thank you very much, this is exactly what I was looking for!